# Windows upgrades destroy dual-boot

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

Some time ago I got a new computer with Windows pre-installed which wouldn't display the GRUB interface no matter what I tried. The solution I thought was to replace the Windows bootmgfw.efi file with the shimx64.efi file. It works fine. The problem is that sometimes Windows decides to install an upgrade which undoes my tweak, so I have to replace the files again.

Does anyone have some idea on how to make the modification permanent?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make it completely permanent unless your system's firmware gives you a way to prevent UEFI variables from being modified (I know of essentially none except for some specific Thinkpad models that have this functionality).

The reason for this is quite simple, Windows maintains it's own internal configuration for the EFI boot manager which it updates the relevant UEFI variables to match every time you boot Windows on the system.  You can update this configuration to avoid needing to replace files (usually, some really stupid UEFI implementations refuse to boot anything else if they see a file at `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`), but it will get reset to the default by Windows every time you install a feature upgrade (or, if on an older Windows version, whenever an update changes something involving the boot process).

If you want to update this configuration, the command is:

```
bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \path
```

Replace `\path` with the path to the boot loader you want to use (using `\` as a path separator, relative to the root of the EFI system partition), and run the command from an administrative PowerShell session.